# Language supporting nested definition of functions

Tags: python, c, function, nested

Which programing languages supports nested definitions of functions?

for example: nested function in python

```
def FuncAsClass():

    x=1             # data members
    def setX(val):  # setter methods
        nonlocal x
        x=val
    def getX():     #getter
        return(x)
    def adder():    # arbitrary state-dependent method
        total=0
        for i in range(x+1):
            total+=i
        return total
    # the interface offered by the class
    interface ={"setX":setX, "getX":getX, "sum":adder }
    return interface
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function#Languages) has a nice summary:

- ALGOL-based languages such as ALGOL 68, Simula, Pascal, Modula-2,
  Modula-3, Oberon, Seed7 and Ada.
- Modern versions of Lisp (with
  lexical scope) such as Scheme, and Common Lisp. ECMAScript
  (JavaScript, and ActionScript).
- Scala (full support)
- Various degrees
  of support in scripting languages such as Ruby, Python, and Perl
  (starting with version 6).
- Standard C and C++ do not support nested functions, but:

  - GCC supports nested functions in C, as a language
    extension.
  - The D language, which is C-related, has nested
    functions.
- Fortran, starting with Fortran-90, supports one level of
  nested (CONTAINed) subroutines and functions.

Comment: `Standard C does not support nested functions` tried mmap-ing memory with R/W/EXEC flag, fill it with code and then typecast the mmap-ed pointer to desired function and use as regular? Ok, it's not a real nested function, but still.

Comment: @kroolik That's even further away from standard C than the various compiler extensions for nested functions.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty... as an example: Racket/Scheme. Consider this:

```
#lang racket

(define (fn x y)
  (define (minus x y)
    (- x y))
  (minus x y))
```